# calculating covariance of groups of 3

Tags: probability, variance, covariance

Q:

We have n bins, each bin can store a group of 3 different elements.

in all groups $S \subseteq \{1,\dots, m\}$, $| S|=3$
$$
  X_{i,j,k} =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if i,j,k are in the same bin} \\
0, & \text{else}
\end{cases}
$$
$$
X=\sum X_{i,j,k} $$
calculate var$(X)$.

A:

I realize that:

$E(X)={m \choose 3}\frac{1} {n^2}$,

var$(\sum X_{i,j,k}$)=${m \choose 3}\frac{1} {n^2}(1-\frac{1}{n^2})$.

because $X\sim B\left({m \choose 3},\frac{1} {n^2}\right)$

I can't figure out how to tackle the Covariance..

Comment: What is $n $ here?

Comment: I was stuck on this for so long that I forgot what the Question was, my bad